# Infinite Loop when trying to keep data UpToDate

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, react-hooks, web-development-server

```
const fetchAllNotes = async () => {
    try {
      console.log("Fetching notes...");
      const response = await fetch(`${host}/notes/fetchAllNotes`, {
        method: "GET",
        headers: {
          "Content-type": "application/json",
          "jwt-token": tkn,
        },
      });
      const json = await response.json();
      console.log(json);
      return (json);

    } catch (error) {
      console.log("Error fetching notes:", error);
      return ([]);
    }
  };
```

-- Above is my function to fetch all notes using api.

//Component I am rendering

```
import { useContext, useEffect, useState } from "react";
import noteContext from "./noteContext";
import {Container} from 'react-bootstrap'
import Noteitem from "./Noteitem";
import AddNote from "./AddNote";

export default function Notes(){
    const {fetchAllNotes} = useContext(noteContext);
    
    const [notes, setNotes] = useState([]);
    

    useEffect(() => {
        async function getNotes(){
            console.log("Use Effect HOOK...");
         const data = await fetchAllNotes();
          setNotes(data);
        }
        getNotes();
      }, []);


    return(<>
    <AddNote />
    <Container>
        <h2>Your Notes: </h2>
        <Container className="row my-2">
        {notes.map(note =>{
            return <Noteitem key={note._id} note={note} />;
        })}
        </Container>
        
    </Container>

    </>)
}
```

-- The problem is it updates the UI on initial render, but if i update or delete a note it won't show up until I refresh the page. If i put the notes(state variable) as dependency in Use effect it starts an infinite loop. I am so struck for last 2 days trying to solve it. Any help is much appreciated / Thank You :D

```
async function getNotes(){
            console.log("Use Effect HOOK...");
         const data = await fetchAllNotes();
          setNotes(data);
        }

useEffect(() => {
        getNotes();
      }, [notes]);
```

-- i tried doing something like this but then it just starts infinite loop

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you put `notes` in the dependencies array of the `useEffect`, the callback of `useEffect` will be executed everytime `notes` is updated (so when `setNoted` is called). That's why you have an infinite loop.

If you want to update your data everytime an action is done, the best way is to separate the function `getNotes` like you did, calling it when the component is initialised (with `useEffect` with an empty dependency array) and every time an operation is done

Like this :

```
const updateNote = async (id, note) => {
   await yourMethodToUpdateTheNote(id, note);
   getNote();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When you perform a CRUD operation, just refresh the data at the bottom of the function.

e.g.

```
const { fetchAllNotes } = useContext(noteContext);

const [notes, setNotes] = useState([]);

const getNotes = async () => {
  const data = await fetchAllNotes();
  setNotes(data);
};

// Initial render
useEffect(() => {
  getNotes();
}, []);

const deleteRecord = async () => {
  await deleteRecord();
  await getNotes(); // Refresh here
};
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is this code:

```js
  useEffect(() => {
    getNotes();
  }, [notes]);
```

You have `getNotes` that depends on `notes`, which is a recursive dependency, just remove the notes from the effect:

```js
  useEffect(() => {
    getNotes();
  }, []);
```

But to fix your problem I suggest putting your setState into the context and when you call `update` or `delete` you fetch new Data and call setState with the results. You also don't need to expose fetchNotes only expose the function that will fetch and set the state.